# Network share folder not accessible on one machine

Tags: networking, windows-server-2008, public-folders

I have a network file share folder available from one server on the network (running Zentyal 3.4/Ubuntu 13.10).  I can access that shared folder from all of the computers on the network, except for one that says the folder is not accessible.  This one computer is running Windows Server 2008.  I have a second Server 2008 machine right next to it that can access the folder just fine.

From the non-working machine, I am able to ping both the IP and the server name of the server successfully.  I have also used "nbtstat -a/-A" on both the name and IP successfully.  However, if I try to do a "net use \servername" to the share or "net use \IPaddress", I get an Error 53.

Everywhere that I have checked shows that File and Printer Sharing is turned on/allowed, including on the network adapters and in the Windows Firewall.  I have also tried different methods of reseting the network adapters and DNS/WINS, but so far no luck.

Any suggestions you may have I would greatly appreciate.